# ¿Cómo puedo entender de forma sencilla la aritmética de punteros en C?

Tags: c, punteros

Sé la teoría y las aplicaciones de los punteros, pero una vez que aparecen punteros a otros punteros mi cabeza sufre una desconexión total.

Comment: Si entiendes lo que es un puntero y lo que puedes hacer con él, sabrás que es una forma indirecta de acceder a una posición de memoria en la que hay otra variable, y por tanto que puedes manipular esa otra variable a través del puntero. Pues nada cambia cuando tienes un puntero a puntero. Simplemente esa otra variable es otro puntero. A través del primero (el que apunta) puedes manipular el segundo (el apuntado). El segundo a su vez apuntará a otra cosa. Quizás sería más fácil ayudarte si pones un ejemplo concreto que no entiendas.

Comment: He visto que has aceptado mi respuesta. En ella explico un poco las bases técnicas de lo que son los punteros y cómo funciona la aritmética de punteros y la desreferenciación. Sin embargo no he entrado en ningún ejemplo de punteros a punteros, tema al que te referías también en la pregunta. No obstante, teniendo claro lo que es un puntero, ya no deberías tener miedo a los punteros a punteros. Si no lo tienes claro puedes hacer otra pregunta, de nuevo con algún ejemplo concreto.

Comment: El comentario en el que planteas el ejemplo del vector de 5 elementos debería formar parte de la pregunta, en vez de ser un comentario. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadirle cosas en el enlace "editar". Después borra el comentario (y yo borraré éste)

Comment: Te sugerimos realizar preguntas en base a [ask] esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones, saludos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La respuesta de PaperBirdMaster es excelente para comprender intuitivamente la idea.

Para dar algún detalle más "técnico" o de bajo nivel, agregaré lo siguiente:

Un puntero es una variable que contiene un número. Ese número es una dirección de memoria. No hay más misterio, de momento. El número puedes verlo si lo imprimes. Por ejemplo:

```
int vector[4];
int *p;

p = vector;
printf("%p\n", p);
```

Hay unos cuantos detalles a señalar en este código.

- El puntero `p`, en el momento en que es declarado, aún no contiene ningún valor. Es un puntero sin inicializar. Del mismo modo que si declaras una variable `int n` y no le das valor está sin inicializar.

  Una variable no inicializada puede ser que tome por defecto el valor 0, pero puede ser que no. Depende del compilador. En general puedes pensar que contiene un dato *aleatorio*. En el caso de `p`, ya que representa una dirección de memoria, diríamos que está *apuntando* a una dirección aleatoria. Eso es peligroso pues a través de `p`  puedes modificar lo que hay en esa dirección y las consecuencias serán imprevisibles (lo más probable es que el programa muera con un *segmentation fault*, pero pueden ocurrir cosas aún peores).
- Por tanto es importante inicializar lo antes posible los punteros. En este código lo inicializo haciéndole apuntar a otra variable. Otra forma típica de inicializarlo es usar `malloc()` para obtener memoria nueva para nuestro proceso y hacer que el puntero apunte a esa nueva memoria.
- Para hacerlo apuntar a otra variable pre-existente la sintaxis habitual sería `p = &otra_variable`, siendo el operador `&` el que permite obtener en qué dirección está esa otra variable. **Sin embargo** si la otra variable es un array, se omite el `&`, ya que **por definición**, el nombre de un array representa la dirección de memoria en la que está su primer elemento. Es decir, `a` es lo mismo que `&a[0]`. Eso explica por qué puedo hacer `p=a`.
- En el `printf()` he usado el formato `%p`, que es típico cuando quieres ver el valor de un puntero, porque te lo muestra en hexadecimal, que es un formato habitualmente más útil para el programador. Pero en el fondon no es más que un número, lo veas en hexadecimal o no (con `%d` podrías verlo en decimal también). Por otro lado observa que imprimo el valor de `p`. No he decorado `p` con nada delante. Si hubiera escrito `&p` lo que vería es en qué dirección está almacenado el propio `p`. Poniendo `p` veo qué valor almacena `p` (es decir, la dirección a que *apunta*). Poniendo `*p` vería el valor apuntado (véase *desreferenciación* más adelante).

Al ejecutar ese programa en pantalla aparece `0x7ffd32b6f8f0`, aunque el número concreto puede variar en cada ejecución. Ese es el número que hay dentro del puntero, y no es otra cosa que la dirección de memoria donde está el primer elemento del array `a`.

### Aritmética de punteros

La aritmética consiste en *sumar o restar* un entero al puntero. Por ejemplo `p+1` le suma 1.

Podría pensarse que el resultado habría de ser `0x7ffd32b6f8f1` (1 más que el valor original que tenía `p`). Pero es que la aritmética de punteros es *rara*, y tiene que serlo por la razón que PaperBirdMaster explicó en su respuesta.

Cuando sumas 1 a un puntero no quieres avanzar a la *dirección de memoria siguiente*, sino al *entero siguiente* (igual que en la analogía con las direcciones de las casas, no quieres avanzar un metro por la acera, sino la cantidad de metros necesaria para llegar a la casa siguiente).

En el caso de los punteros, eso implica que cuando tu escribes `p+n`, siendo `n` un entero, el compilador hace en realidad `p+ n*sizeof(int)`, en este caso, ya que `p` se declaró como puntero a `int`. Es decir, se le suma a `p` la cantidad de bytes necesaria para llegar al siguiente entero.

Si el tamaño de un `int` es 4, entonces `p+1` en realidad sumará 4 a `p`. El resultado será por tanto `0x7ffd32b6f8f4`.

Puedes comprobarlo con el siguiente código:

```
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%p\n", p+1);
```

Aunque mentalmente puedes simplemente leer `p+1` como "la dirección del siguiente `int` después de la dirección apuntada por `p`", y olvidarte de que el compilador en realidad suma 4. En general sumará el número de bytes que ocupa el tipo apuntado por `p`. Esta es una de las razones por las que tienes que declarar el tipo apuntado por `p`.

### Desreferenciación

Cuando pones un `*` delante de una expresión que es "de tipo puntero" (es decir, es una dirección de memoria), entonces estarás accediendo **al contenido** de esa dirección.

De este modo si pones `*p`, estarás accediendo a lo que hay en la dirección de memoria `0x7ffd32b6f8f0` que, como sabemos, es el primer elemento del array `a`. Puedes modificarlo si haces `*p = 3`, por ejemplo. O leerlo si haces por ejemplo `printf("%d\n", *p)`.

Y juntando esto con lo antes explicado, `*(p+1)` te servirá para acceder al *siguiente* elemento dentro del array `a`.

Fijate que si intentas acceder a `*(p+8)`, por ejemplo, sería equivalente a intentar acceder a `a[8]`. Ya que ese elemento no existe, habrá problemas.

### Todo junto

Usemos estos conocimientos para resolver el problema que planteas. Un array de 5 elementos y el uso de un puntero para recorrerlo y mostrar los resultados.

Tienes dos formas de hacerlo:

- Usar expresiones de tipo `*(p+i)` para ir accediendo a cada elemento del array (`i` sería un entero que representaría el índice dentro del array).
- Usar expresiones de tipo `p = p +1` (o equivalentemente `p++`) para *incrementar* el propio puntero `p`, de modo que vaya accediendo a cada elemento del array.

Solución con el primer enfoque:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a[5] = {1, 4, 7, 9, 3};
  int *p = a;

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, *(p+i));
  }
}
```

Usando el segundo enfoque (voy a hacerlo en este caso con un bucle `while` en vez de un `for`, para variar, pero podrías hacerlo también con el `for`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a[5] = {1, 4, 7, 9, 3};
  int *p = a;
  int i = 0;

  while (i<5) {
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, *p);
    i++;
    p++;
  }
}
```

La diferencia más importante entre ambos enfoques es que en el primer caso, al terminar el bucle, `p` aún apunta al primer elemento del array, puesto que *no cambiamos su valor* en el bucle. En el segundo caso en cambio al salir del bucle `p` estará apuntando ya fuera del array, puesto que en cada iteración estamos "incrementando" su valor (pongo incrementar entre comillas porque, debido a la aritmética de punteros, no es un incremento normal de 1 en 1, sino de `sizeof(int)` en `sizeof(int)`.

Dependiendo del contexto puede interesarte más un enfoque u otro.

**Bonus**. La sintaxis `*(p+i)` es tan habitual que los diseñadoras del C inventaron una sintaxis alternativa más simple: `p[i]`. Esta sintaxis no obstante es muy confusa para los principiantes, ya que es exactamente la misma sintaxis que se usa con los arrays. Y es intencionado que sea la misma sintaxis, porque es el contexto en que se usa, un puntero que apunta a un array.

De hecho, de forma general, cuando el compilador ve algo con la pinta: `x[y]`, lo que ejecuta en realidad es `*(x+y)`. Por eso funciona tanto con punteros como en `p[2]`, que llevará a `*(p+2)`, como en "verdaderos" arrays, como `a[2]`, puesto que la expresión será interpretada como `*(a+2)`, y ya hemos visto que `a` (el nombre del array) equivale a la dirección de memoria donde está su primer elemento, por lo que `a+2` estará haciendo también aritmética de punteros para acceder dos enteros más allá.

Answer (score 4):

La aritmética de punteros es sencilla, si tienes una dirección de memoria y le sumas X, estarás a X posiciones de la dirección de memoria original.

*Si tienes la dirección de la primera casa y te dicen que vayas a la quinta casa empezando por la de la dirección que tienes, contarás cinco casas y llamarás al timbre: has hecho aritmética de direcciones de casas*:

[image]

---

Vamos a añadir un nivel de puntero más.

*Si tienes un código postal, cada código postal tiene varias calles, y cada calle varias casas. Si te dicen que sumes cinco al código postal 08100 (Mollet Del Valles, Barcelona), irás al código postal 08105 (Municipio de Conreria, Barcelona): has hecho aritmética de códigos postales*.

---

Vamos a añadir más niveles de puntero.

*Si tienes un código de provincia, cada provincia tiene ciudades, cada ciudad tiene códigos postales, cada código postal tiene calles, cada calle tiene casas. Si te dicen que sumes cinco al código 28 (Madrid), irás al código 33 (Asturias). Has hecho aritmética de códigos de provincia*.

---

La aritmética de punteros funciona de la misma manera, cuando haces una operación aritmética (por ejemplo, suma) con un nivel, avanzas en ese nivel.